# ng-repeat $index interpolation inside ng-if

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ng-if

In my app I have nested forms, some with fixed names and some with generated names using ng-repeat index:

```
<form name="rootForm"> 
    <div ng-repeat="child in childForms">
        <ng-form name="childForm_{{$index}}">
            <!-- form content-->
        </ng-form>
    </div>
    <ng-form name="fixedName">
        <!-- form content-->
    </ng-form>
    <ng-form name="anotherFixedName">
        <!-- form content-->
    </ng-form>
</form>
```

In the same html file, I want to access those forms $valid property through ng-if statement. Is that possible?
I'm trying with:

```
<div>
    <div ng-repeat="child in childForms">
        <div ng-if="rootForm.childForm_[$index].$valid">
            Child form {{index}} is valid! 
        </div>
    </div>
    <div ng-if="rootForm.fixedName.$valid"> Valid! </div>
    <div ng-if="rootForm.anotherFixedName.$valid"> Valid! </div>
</div>
```

And it works fine with forms with fixed names. But for child forms with generated names it does not. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you try putting ng-repeat="child in childForms track by $index"?

Comment: Think there is no need for "track by $index", even withouth that child form names are generated successfully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your repeated element with `ng-if` uses an expression which won't do as you'd expect.

Instead of:

```
<div ng-if="rootForm.childForm_[$index].$valid">
```

It should probably be:

```
<div ng-if="rootForm['childForm_' + $index].$valid">
```

In the former, the markup would've been trying to access a property named exactly as `childForm_[$index]`.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
<div ng-if="rootForm['childForm_' + $index].$valid">
```

Comment: That's invalid syntax, not sure if you meant to keep the first `.` there

Comment: Correct, it was a mistake, thanks. Updated the answer.